# Как узнать оператора у пользователя на android?

Tags: android, java

Как узнать оператора у пользователя на android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как то так

```
final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
    //или 
    telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
```

и не забываем про манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @andreich спасибо, работает первый способ, второй показывает цифры, может код оператора!

Comment: А как сделать так сделать так , чтоб название отображались в text view?

Comment: @NikitaBellik прочитайте вот это http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/textview.php должно помочь